# Breeze Creating Complex Entities with Lookup Tables

Tags: breeze

I am new to Angular and Breeze. I am trying to create a new group with customer relationships at the same time. My DB structure has 3 tables that are affected the Groups, UserToGroups and the CustomersToGroups tables. The entity manager has the tables and references registered. My question is, do I need to first create the group before I can add the records to the lookup tables? If a groupId does not exist it should not be able to create a UserToGroups record or a CustomersToGroups record. Is Breeze and the entity manager handling all of this? Can I do this all in one shot? How?

```
controller.js
function addCustAndGroup(CustId, grpId, GroupCategory, GroupDesc) {
 var newGroup = app.dataservice.manager.createEntity("Group");
 newGroup.GroupId(CustId);
 newGroup.GroupCategory(GroupCategory);
 newGroup.GroupDescription(GroupDesc);
 manager.StudnetsToGroup.push(studentToGroup);
 manager.UserToGroup.push(userToGroup);
 manager.saveChanges();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out something that you're doing that I find worrisome: your `dataservice` exposes the manager to its caller. A key reason for *having* a `dataservice` is to encapsulate the EntityManager ... to hide it from all callers. If you're going to expose the manager to callers, why bother with the dataservice at all?

I don't have a lot of absolute rules but you've broken one of the few, namely "*never expose the EntityManager from the dataservice.*"  I have never had to relax that rule. I promise you that you will regret breaking it.

I think what you want to do is have your dataservice expose a `createGroup` method. All of the work of creating the group should be tucked inside the `dataservice`.

Now that I'm done ranting, I'm trying to make sense of your actual question and your code. I'm sorry but I'm kind of lost. I'm stumped by `manager.UserToGroup.push` because (a) the EntityManager doesn't have a `UserToGroup` member and (b) there is no `push` method in the Breeze API ... certainly nothing like that for adding/attaching entities to the EntityManager cache.

I don't know which of your "tables" are "lookup tables". I'm kind of confused by the words "table" and "record" anyway as you seem really to be talking about entity type and entity instances, not database objects. I get the parallelism but it's worth maintaining a clear distinction between entities and the database structures to which they are mapped.

A final confession of my confusion: your question subject refers to "Complex Entities". Breeze has a notion called "Complex Type". I don't think that's what you mean. I think you mean that you believe your Entity is complicated. Is that right?

I sense that none of this is getting closer to an answer to your question ... which I cannot quite fathom. It seems to be about whether you have to create one type of entity before a different type. But I can't be sure.

I think you'll have to clarify your question before you get a proper answer.